# Mitigating the Caribbean Hurricane season (2016)

Tags: insurance, weather-and-climate, caribbean

We would like to visit a Caribbean island (currently looking at either somewhere in the Bahamas or Puerto Rico, but totally flexible) in the last week of August (EG Smack in the middle of hurricane season).  I have seen some stats that suggest the 2016 season will be the most active since 2012 with the potential of 14 named storms.

Given that the risk of encountering a hurricane is a percentages game, what measures would you take to mitigate the possibility of a hurricane hitting my destination for the desired dates?  (Or is the risk high enough that somewhere else would be a better destination.)

EG Is standard travel insurance enough to protect me financially?
Should we prefer North/South/East/West in the Caribbean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NOAA has some month-by-month hurricane incidence maps [on their website.](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/climo/) They're only meant to be qualitative, but they can give you a sense of what you're up against:

[image]
[image]

From this we see:

- The [ABC islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_islands_(Lesser_Antilles)), along with Trinidad & Tobago, are less commonly affected by hurricanes than most of the rest of the Caribbean.  All of these islands are relatively close to the South American mainland, and so take a little longer to get to from the continental US;  but the extra travel time might be worth it in this case.
- Cuba is relatively less-frequently hit than other Caribbean islands (perhaps due to the sheltering effects of nearby Hispaniola?)  US citizens will have trouble traveling here, of course.
- If you want to avoid hurricanes, Puerto Rico and the [Leeward Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leeward_Islands) are not the best choices during the months of August and September.  The Bahamas, Jamaica, and Hispaniola are better, but probably not much.

Finally, note that [hurricane tracks can go pretty much anywhere in the Caribbean (warning: huge image file);](http://www.nhc.noaa.gov/climo/images/1851_2013_tc.jpg) just because you decide to go to Aruba doesn't mean you won't be affected by a hurricane.  I would probably buy travel insurance for peace of mind in a case like this, but YMMV.

Comment: I'm not a US citizen, so I can easily get to Cuba   .. but my wife wouldn't be happy with me going by myself .. specially as it's for her birthday!  (BTW a US cruise ship docked there today).   Also I consider travel insurance a must for any sort of international travel.

Comment: I probably don't buy travel insurance as often as I should, to be honest.  I've been lucky so far, but my luck will probably run out some day...

Comment: Given the % cost of travel insurance in the total travel cost I see it as a no brainer.  Last christmas we spent $USD7K just on flights alone for 2 people just to get to Australia for Christmas (damned high season) so $300 for travel insurance is nothing.

Comment: A few months later, my advice to travel to the ABC islands in September [does not look so sage.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Matthew#Lesser_Antilles_and_South_America)

Comment: The fun thing is that right now I am in Ft Lauderdale for work and how Mathew acts will directly affect what I am able to do!